# Is Transfer Acceleration working? response location and object URL is different

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm uploading a video to S3 using aws-sdk in a reaction environment.
And Use an accelerated endpoint for faster data transfers.

the endpoint is `bucket-name.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com`

And I changed the option to 'Enabled' for accelerating transmission in bucket properties.

Below is my code for uploading file objects to s3.

```js
import AWS from "aws-sdk";

require("dotenv").config();

const AWS_ACCESS_KEY = process.env.REACT_APP_AWS_ACCESS_KEY;
const AWS_SECRET_KEY = process.env.REACT_APP_AWS_SECRET_KEY;
const BUCKET = process.env.REACT_APP_BUCKET_NAME;
const REGION = process.env.REACT_APP_REGION;

AWS.config.update({
  accessKeyId: AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
  secretAccessKey: AWS_SECRET_KEY,
  region: REGION,
  useAccelerateEndpoint: true, //----> the options is here.
});

async function uploadFileToS3(file) {
  const params = {
    Bucket: BUCKET,
    Key: file.name,
    ContentType: 'multipart/form-data',
    Body: file
  };

  const accelerateOption = {
     Bucket: BUCKET,
     AccelerateConfiguration: { Status: 'Enabled'},
     ExpectedBucketOwner: process.env.REACT_APP_BUCKET_OWNER_ID,
  };

  const s3 = new AWS.S3();

  try {
    s3.putBucketAccelerateConfiguration(accelerateOption, (err, data) => {
      if (err) console.log(err)
      else console.log(data, 'data put accelerate') //----> this is just object {}
    });

    s3.upload(params)
      .on("httpUploadProgress", progress => {
        const { loaded, total } = progress;
        const progressPercentage = parseInt((loaded / total) * 100);
        console.log(progressPercentage);
       })
      .send((err, data) => {
          console.log(data, 'data data');
       });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

There is definitely s3-accelerate in url in the location property of the data object. (in console.log)

```
{
  Bucket: "newvideouploada2f16b1e1d6a4671947657067c79824b121029-dev"
  ETag: "\"d0b40e4afca23137bee89b54dd2ebcf3-8\""
  Key: "Raw Run __ Race Against the Storm.mp4"
  Location: "https://newvideouploada2f16b1e1d6a4671947657067c79824b121029-dev.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com/Raw+Run+__+Race+Aga
}
```

However, the object URL of the property of the video I uploaded does not exist.
Is this how it's supposed to be?

Am I using Transfer Acceleration wrong way?
I saw the documentation and AWS said using `putBucketAccelerateConfiguration`.
But When I console.log there is noting responsed.

Please let me know How to use Transfer Acceleration in Javascript awd-sdk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running this code on some AWS compute (EC2, ECS, EKS, Lambda), and the bucket is in the same region as your compute, then consider using `VPC Gateway endpoints` for `S3`. More information [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/privatelink/vpce-gateway.html). If the compute and the bucket are in different regions, consider using [VPC Endpoints for S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/privatelink/vpc-endpoints-s3.html) with inter region [VPC peering](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/peering/what-is-vpc-peering.html). Note: VPC Gateway endpoints are free while VPC Endpoints are not.

After you enable `BucketAccelerate` it takes **at least half an hour to take effect**. You don't need to call this every time you upload a file unless you are also suspending bucket acceleration after you are done.

Bucket acceleration helps when you want to use the AWS backbone network to upload data faster(may be user is in region 'A' and bucket is in region 'B' or you want to upload bigger files in which case it goes to the nearest edge location and then uses the AWS backbone network). You can use [this](https://s3-accelerate-speedtest.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com/en/accelerate-speed-comparsion.html) tool to check the potential improvement in terms of speed for various regions.

Also there is additional cost when you use this feature. Check the Data Transfer section on the S3 [pricing page](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/).